# Modify option in Developer tab is missing

Tags: vba, excel

I attempted to add a description of my add-in by

```
Choose Developer➪Modify➪Document Panel
```

But there is no Modify option under Developer tab on my Excel (I am using Office 365ProPlus). How do I display this option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The description of an Excel add-in is taken from the "Comments" Document property which can be found here: File, Info, click the "Properties" dropdown and select "Advanced Properties". Whatever you type into the "Title" box is what will appear in the list of add-ins once your add-in has been selected.

Comment: Basically, the method I listed above is outdated?

Comment: I don't know, the description of an Excel add-in (Excel file saved as an add-in) has always worked the way I decribed: through the document properties. The way you access document properties has changed over the versions of Excel for sure. I described how to get there in 2016 (365)